# In ggplot2 how to plot the bar plot in a descending order

Tags: r, ggplot2

The dataset pattern is:
[image]

The code I am running is:

ggplot(df_bar, aes(x = reorder(Industry, -value), y = value, fill = variable)) +
geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')

Presently the sorting of descending order is calculated based on each industry's average, but I want the sorting to be done only based on variable == 'ret'. How to accomplish it?

Comment: More research would have led you to this conclusion: every question on how to order something (axis, facets, etc) in `ggplot2` are resolved by converting the variable in question to a `factor` and controlling the order of its `levels`.

Comment: I know you started down that road with your use of `reorder`, btw, it's the last dupe-link that covers bars within groups. If that does not resolve your issue, please [edit] your question, add usable data (I won't scrape a pic of data) using the output of `dput(df_bar)` to a [code block], show your updated code, and then @-ping me. We'll sort through it then. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks your comment motivated me to make a new order variable for rank the value based on ret, and I assigned the same rank to ret_pm and ret_py. There might be simple ways to do it but for the moment it worked for me.

Comment: That is a great way to do it! Glad you got it to work.